# Información de un usuario de la pagina no actualiza

Tags: php

Comienza la parte de pacientes y tengo la opcion de actualizar datos de los pacientes, pero al momento de guardar me manda un mensaje en el header que no se actualizo porque algo salio mal.

Primero es `pacientes.php`, luego `editar_paciente.php` y finalmente `procesar_editar_paciente.php`. Me estoy basando de otra pestaña de este mismo, porque hay 3 cosas de esta pagina: pacientes, medicos y medicamentos. La de médicos ya esta hecha, agrega, edita y eliminar al 100% pero al hacer lo mismo con pacientes me manda error con editar pacientes. Se puede agregar pacientes pero no edita. Me falta también eliminar pero no tengo mucho problema con ella.

Aquí esta la primera.

```
<?php session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['elusuario'])) { // VALIDAMOS QUE EXISTA LA SESIÓN 

    include('./layout/cabecera.php');
?>
    <h1>Pacientes</h1>
    <a href="agregar_paciente.php" class="btn">Agregar Nuevo Paciente</a>
    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['respuesta'])) {
        echo "<div class='card-panel red darken-1'>" . $_GET['respuesta'] . "</div>";
    }
    ?>
    <p>A continuación se muestra la lista de Pacientes registrados en el sistema.</p>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Nombre completo</th>
                <th>Acción</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <?php
            require_once('./includes/conexion.php');
            $sql2 = "SELECT id_paciente,CONCAT(nombre_paciente,' ',apellidos_paciente) AS nombre_completo FROM pacientes where estatus >0";
            $consulta2 = $conexion->prepare($sql2);
            $consulta2->execute();
            $resultado2 = $consulta2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $i = 1;
            if ($consulta2->rowCount() > 0) {
                foreach ($resultado2 as $registro2) {
                    echo "
          <tr>
            <td>" . $i++ . "</td>
            <td>" . $registro2->nombre_completo . "</td> 
            <td>
                <a class='btn' href='editar_paciente.php?id=" . $registro2->id_paciente . "'>Editar</a>
                <a class='btn' onclick='javascript:eliminar(" . $registro2->id_paciente . ")'>Eliminar</a>
            </td>
          </tr>  ";
                }
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
        function eliminar(valor) {
            if (confirm("¿Desea eliminar al paciente seleccionado?")) {
                location.href = "eliminar_paciente.php?id=" + valor;
            }
        }
    </script>
<?php
    include('./layout/pie.php');
} else {
    header('location:index.php');
}
?>
```

Al dar click en editar me dirige en esta parte.

```
<?php session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['elusuario'])) { // VALIDAMOS QUE EXISTA LA SESIÓN 

    include('./layout/cabecera.php');
?>
    <h1>Edición de Paciente</h1>
    <?php
    require_once('./includes/conexion.php');
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $elIDp = $_GET['id'];
        $consulta2 = "select * from pacientes where id_paciente=:elidp";
        $sql2 = $conexion->prepare($consulta2);
        $sql2->bindParam(':elidp', $elIDp);
        $sql2->execute();
        $resultado2 = $sql2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        if ($sql2->rowCount() > 0) {
            $elnombrep = $resultado2[0]->nombre_paciente;
            $elapellidosp = $resultado2[0]->apellidos_paciente;
            $laedadp = $resultado2[0]->edad;
            $lafechap = $resultado2[0]->fecha_alta;
            $elestatusp = $resultado2[0]->estatus;
    ?>
            <form action="procesar_editar_paciente.php" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $elIDp; ?>">
                <label>Nombre</label>
                <input name="nombre" value="<?= $elnombrep; ?> ">
                <label>Apellidos</label>
                <input name="apellidos" value="<?= $elapellidosp; ?> ">
                <label>Edad</label>
                <input name="edad" value="<?= $laedadp; ?> ">
                <label>Fecha</label>
                <input name="fecha_alta" value="<?= $lafechap; ?> ">
                <label>Estatus</label>
                <p>
                    <label>
                        <input class="with-gap" name="estatus" value="1" type="radio" <?= ($elestatusp == 1) ? 'checked' : ''; ?> />
                        <span>Activo</span>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input class="with-gap" name="estatus" value="2" type="radio" <?= ($elestatusp == 2) ? 'checked' : ''; ?> />
                        <span>Inactivo</span>
                    </label>
                </p>
                <button type="submit" name="editarp" class="btn">Guardar cambios</button>
            </form>
<?php
        } // fin del if de row count

    } // fin del isset

    include('./layout/pie.php');
} else {
    header('location:index.php');
}
?>
```

Y finalmente pasa por aquí, pero me manda mensaje de error, lo que no entiendo porque yo habia hecho uno de estos antes.

```
<?php

include_once('./includes/conexion.php');
try {
    if (isset($_POST['editarp'])) {
        $elidp = $_POST['id'];
        $nombrep = $_POST['nombre'];
        $apellidosp = $_POST['apellidos'];
        $edadp = $_POST['edad'];
        $fechap = $_POST['fecha_alta'];
        $estatusp = $_POST['estatus'];
        $sql2 = "update pacientes set nombre_paciente=:elnombrep, apellidos_paciente=:elapellidosp,
        edad=laedadp, fecha=:lafechap, estatus=:elestatusp where id_paciente=:elidp";
        $sql2 = $conexion->prepare($sql2);

        $sql2->bindParam(':elnombrep', $nombrep);
        $sql2->bindParam(':elapellidosp', $apellidosp);
        $sql2->bindParam(':laedadp', $edadp);
        $sql2->bindParam(':lafechap', $fechap);
        $sql2->bindParam(':elestatusp', $estatusp);
        $sql2->bindParam(':elidp', $elidp);

        $sql2->execute();
        header('location:pacientes.php?respuesta=El paciente fue modificado correctamente');
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    header('location:pacientes.php?respuesta=Eror al editar el paciente');
}
```

Comment: Hay 2 errores de sintaxis y una advertencia. Lo pongo como comentario porque esto encaja más en errores tipográficos que en un problema real. Problema 1 y 2, en la consulta `$sql2 = "update pacientes ..."`, la parte `edad=laedadp` debe ser `edad=:laedad` y `fecha=:lafechap` debe ser `fecha_alta=:lafechap`. La advertencia es que estas metiendo espacios en blanco adicionales en todos los inputs en el segundo código, elimina el espacio entre el cierre de php y el cierre de comillas.